# How do I construct an array of dates in a given date range using snowsql?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Given two dates, I would like to create an array that holds all of the days between those dates and then filter it to contain only the days that fall at the end of a month.

For example, with `start_date` `2019-01-31` and `end_date` `2019-06-30`, I would to construct the array

```
[
  '2019-01-31',
  '2019-02-28',
  '2019-03-31',
  '2019-04-30',
  '2019-05-31',
  '2019-06-30'
]
```

Comment: The dates in your example/array are strange, including non-existant 31-06-2019.  I suppose you want consecutive dates, but your example looks like "almost end-of-month".  Please update your question with correct details.

Answer (score 7):

It's a little hard to understand *exactly* what you want, but from the requested output it looks like the array contains monthly dates between two date limits.  I tried to implement using JavaScript to avoid the dreaded "Unsupported subquery" error, but it's hard to calculate dates, format them and return from JavaScript to SQL.
So I ended up with an SQL UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ARRAY_MONTHS_BETWEEN("FROM" DATE, "TO" DATE)
RETURNS ARRAY AS 
'
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DATEADD(MONTH, "MONTH" , "FROM")) A
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) - 1 "MONTH"
        FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 1000)))
  WHERE "MONTH" <= CEIL(DATEDIFF(MONTHS, "FROM", "TO"))
';
```

It can be tricky to use this function except with date constants, because you risk opening Pandora's box of Snowflake correlated subqueries.  But then again, maybe not.

Comment: nod we have a two processes that do similar stuff, one creates a temp table in the session with the "years worth of days" using a create table with constants dates inserted (using a {{mustache}} syntax)  and another date dimension table that is years ahead/behind.. and use them to suit needs while avoid huge table scans.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to achieve that by creating a calendar table in Snowflake

Comment: "Rainbow tables" for date calculations are great eg. in a data warehousing environment.  Using semi-structured data, eg. arrays, may simplify storage at the (slight?) expense of efficiency and handling.

Answer (score 6):

The Snowflake **LAST_DAY** function can be used to fetch the last day of every month that is between the two dates 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/last_day.html.

```
SELECT 
  ARRAY_AGG(LAST_DAY(MY_DATE))
FROM (
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, SEQ4(), '2019-01-31')) AS MY_DATE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>20000))
  WHERE MY_DATE <= '2019-06-30'
);
```

The above query will also wrap the result in an array https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html

```
[
  "2019-01-31",
  "2019-02-28",
  "2019-03-31",
  "2019-04-30",
  "2019-05-31",
  "2019-06-30"
]
```

As already suggested, you can optionally use this sql to create a new user-defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LAST_DATES_TO_ARRAY(FROM_D DATE, TO_D DATE)
RETURNS ARRAY 
AS 
$$
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(LAST_DAY(MY_DATE))
FROM (
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, SEQ4(), FROM_D)) AS MY_DATE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>20000))
  WHERE MY_DATE <= TO_D
)
$$;
```

Comment: This is pretty great! Thank you for your help, if you are interested the Snowflake Community has  Select Star program that adds points to your profile if you are a register Snowflake user, check out the page and sign up if you are interested: https://community.snowflake.com/s/selectstar

Answer (score 4):

Building on what previous responders have provided, the following should work for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LAST_DATES_TO_ARRAY(FROM_DT DATE, TO_DT DATE)
RETURNS ARRAY 
AS 
$$
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT LAST_DAY(MY_DATE))
FROM (
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, SEQ4(), FROM_DT)) AS MY_DATE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>2000000))
  WHERE MY_DATE <= TO_DT
  ORDER BY 1
)
$$;

SELECT LAST_DATES_TO_ARRAY(DATEADD('YEARS', -1, CURRENT_DATE()), CURRENT_DATE()) AS my_array;

 MY_ARRAY
["2018-11-30",
 "2018-12-31",
 "2019-01-31",
 "2019-02-28",
 "2019-03-31",
 "2019-04-30",
 "2019-05-31",
 "2019-06-30",
 "2019-07-31",
 "2019-08-31",
 "2019-09-30",
 "2019-10-31"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative sql only solution - start and end dates go into the current_date() spots.

It's super quick to generate all the month ends for 10000 years placing today in the middle (365|180 * 10000) then just predicate the answer with sed start and end dates prior to placing into an array. runs in 202ms

No functions, uses cache, less testing, etc etc.

```
select array_agg(distinct my_date) 
from ( 
      SELECT 
      last_day( DATEADD(DAY, -1*SEQ4(), CURRENT_DATE()+(180*10000)),month) AS MY_DATE 
      FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => (365*10000) ))  
      where 
          my_date between 
          current_date() -39 and 
          current_date() +80 
      )
```

[image]